# Function not returning value (Python 2.7)

Tags: python, python-2.7, return

I am trying to implement a bisection method function in Python 2.7. I am really stumped as to why my code isn't returning the root that I am bracketing in my test.

When I put print statements in the code, it is clear that the algorithm is finding the root, but I must have missed something basic in the actual syntax (I am a complete newby to python).

Code is here:

```
def bisection(a,b,fun,tol):
    c = (a+b)/2.0
    if (b-a)/2.0 <= tol:
        #Debugging print statement 1:
        #print 'SOL1: c = ', c
        return c

    if fun(c) == 0:
        #Debugging print statement 2:
        #print 'SOL2: c = ', c
        return c

    elif fun(a)*fun(c) < 0:
        b = c
    else:
        a = c
    print 'a =', a
    print 'b =', b
    bisection(a, b, fun, tol)

def tstr(x):
    return 2*(x**2) - 3*x + 1

sol = bisection(0, 0.9, tstr, 0.01)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are ignoring the recursive call at the end; you do need to explicitly return its return value:

```
return bisection(a, b, fun, tol)
```

Not using `return` here means the recursive call return value is just ignored, and the *outer* calling function ends without an explicit `return` stamenent, thus returns `None`.

With this change, `sol` is actually set:

```
>>> sol = bisection(0, 0.9, tstr, 0.01)
a = 0.45
b = 0.9
a = 0.45
b = 0.675
a = 0.45
b = 0.5625
a = 0.45
b = 0.50625
a = 0.478125
b = 0.50625
a = 0.4921875
b = 0.50625
>>> sol
0.49921875
```